# Android AsynchTask repeating process for half an our

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I have an asynctask with a progressbar. What i need in doInBackground() is to fill my database  and post it with horisontal progressbar.
But it run again an again and again the database fill and i don't know why.

Please help me to modify it!
Thank you!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Db_ReFill db_refill;
    ProgressDialog progressBar;
    private int progressBarStatus = 0;
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db_refill = new Db_ReFill();

    progressBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressBar.setMessage("Várjááá!");
            progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressBar.setCancelable(false);
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
    }

    class dbFrissites extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBar.show();
            progressBarStatus = 0;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            while (progressBarStatus < 100) {
                progressBarStatus++;
                publishProgress(progressBarStatus);
                db_refill.fill();

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: the DB_Refill.class

```
public class Db_ReFill {

    private static Context context = MainActivity.context;
    static DatabaseHandler db= new DatabaseHandler(context);
    public static Boolean kesz = false;

    public void fill(){
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Adatbázis szótárak feltöltése ...");
        db.addAccuracyVocab(new AccuracyVocab("1"));
        db.addAccuracyVocab(new AccuracyVocab("0,5"));
        db.addAccuracyVocab(new AccuracyVocab("0,25"));
        db.addAccuracyVocab(new AccuracyVocab("0,1"));
        db.addAccuracyVocab(new AccuracyVocab("0,01"));
        db.addAccuracyVocab(new AccuracyVocab("0,001"));
        db.addAccuracyVocab(new AccuracyVocab("-"));

        db.addEngineTypeVocab(new EngineTypeVocab("G", "Gáz"));
        db.addEngineTypeVocab(new EngineTypeVocab("H", "Hibrid"));
        db.addEngineTypeVocab(new EngineTypeVocab("E", "Elektromos"));
        db.addEngineTypeVocab(new EngineTypeVocab("B", "Benzin"));
        db.addEngineTypeVocab(new EngineTypeVocab("D", "Dízel"));

        db.addEnvironmentalClassificationVocab(new EnvironmentalClassificationVocab(
                "0",
                "Katalizátor nélküli benzin motoros, nem minősített dízel motoros"));
        db.addEnvironmentalClassificationVocab(new EnvironmentalClassificationVocab(
                "1", "Katalizátoros, nem szabályozott benzin motoros"));
        db.addEnvironmentalClassificationVocab(new EnvironmentalClassificationVocab(
                "2", "Katalizátoros, szabályozott benzin motoros"));
        db.addEnvironmentalClassificationVocab(new EnvironmentalClassificationVocab(
                "3", "Dízel EURO-I"));
        db.addEnvironmentalClassificationVocab(new EnvironmentalClassificationVocab(
                "4", "Dízel és benzines EURO-II"));
        db.addEnvironmentalClassificationVocab(new EnvironmentalClassificationVocab(
                "5", "Tiszta gázüzemű vagy elektromos vagy hibrid"));
        db.addEnvironmentalClassificationVocab(new EnvironmentalClassificationVocab(
                "6", "Benzines EURO-III, OBD"));
        db.addEnvironmentalClassificationVocab(new EnvironmentalClassificationVocab(
                "7", "Dízel EURO-III"));
        db.addEnvironmentalClassificationVocab(new EnvironmentalClassificationVocab(
                "8", "Dízel EURO-III OBD"));
        db.addEnvironmentalClassificationVocab(new EnvironmentalClassificationVocab(
                "9", "Benzines EURO-IV, OBD"));
        db.addEnvironmentalClassificationVocab(new EnvironmentalClassificationVocab(
                "10", "Dízel EURO-IV OBD1"));
        db.addEnvironmentalClassificationVocab(new EnvironmentalClassificationVocab(
                "11", "Dízel EURO-IV OBD2"));
        db.addEnvironmentalClassificationVocab(new EnvironmentalClassificationVocab(
                "12", "Dízel EURO-V, OBD"));
        db.addEnvironmentalClassificationVocab(new EnvironmentalClassificationVocab(
                "13", "Dízel OBD EEV"));
        db.addEnvironmentalClassificationVocab(new EnvironmentalClassificationVocab(
                "14", "EURO-V"));
        db.addEnvironmentalClassificationVocab(new EnvironmentalClassificationVocab(
                "15", "EURO-VI"));
        db.addEnvironmentalClassificationVocab(new EnvironmentalClassificationVocab(
                "98", "Ismeretlen"));
        db.addEnvironmentalClassificationVocab(new EnvironmentalClassificationVocab(
                "99", "Nem értelmezhető"));

        db.addFielddeVicevocab(new FieldDeviceVocab("EMBase"));
        db.addFielddeVicevocab(new FieldDeviceVocab("PT1004"));
        db.addFielddeVicevocab(new FieldDeviceVocab("PT1008"));
        db.addFielddeVicevocab(new FieldDeviceVocab("Altivar 71"));
        db.addFielddeVicevocab(new FieldDeviceVocab("UMI-16"));
        db.addFielddeVicevocab(new FieldDeviceVocab("DIRIS A10"));
        db.addFielddeVicevocab(new FieldDeviceVocab("EMPV"));
        db.addFielddeVicevocab(new FieldDeviceVocab("GR"));

        db.addMagnitudeVocab(new MagnitudeVocab("1000000000000"));
        db.addMagnitudeVocab(new MagnitudeVocab("1000000000"));
        db.addMagnitudeVocab(new MagnitudeVocab("1000000"));
        db.addMagnitudeVocab(new MagnitudeVocab("1000"));
        db.addMagnitudeVocab(new MagnitudeVocab("1"));
        db.addMagnitudeVocab(new MagnitudeVocab("0,001"));
        db.addMagnitudeVocab(new MagnitudeVocab("0,000001"));
        db.addMagnitudeVocab(new MagnitudeVocab("0,000000001"));
        db.addMagnitudeVocab(new MagnitudeVocab("1E-12"));
        db.addMagnitudeVocab(new MagnitudeVocab("0.1"));
        db.addMagnitudeVocab(new MagnitudeVocab("0.01"));
        db.addMagnitudeVocab(new MagnitudeVocab("22.5"));

        db.addPhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab(new PhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab("Nincs"));
        db.addPhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab(new PhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab("Másodperc"));
        db.addPhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab(new PhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab("Fok"));
        db.addPhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab(new PhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab("Sebesség"));
        db.addPhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab(new PhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab("Százalék"));
        db.addPhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab(new PhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab("Hőmérséklet"));
        db.addPhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab(new PhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab("Nyomás"));
        db.addPhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab(new PhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab("Impulszus sebesség"));
        db.addPhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab(new PhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab("Fordulatszám"));
        db.addPhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab(new PhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab("Térfogat"));
        db.addPhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab(new PhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab("Térfogatáram"));
        db.addPhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab(new PhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab("Gyorsulás"));
        db.addPhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab(new PhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab("Sugárzás"));
        db.addPhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab(new PhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab("Áramerősség"));
        db.addPhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab(new PhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab("Feszültség"));
        db.addPhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab(new PhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab("Frekvencia"));
        db.addPhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab(new PhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab("Teljesítmény"));
        db.addPhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab(new PhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab("Teljesítmény tényező"));
        db.addPhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab(new PhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab("Hőáram"));
        db.addPhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab(new PhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab("Mágnesszelep"));
        db.addPhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab(new PhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab("Motorkapcsoló"));
        db.addPhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab(new PhysicalUnitTypeNameVocab("Hibaszenzor"));

        db.addSensorsNameVocab(new SensorsNameVocab("GPS"));
        db.addSensorsNameVocab(new SensorsNameVocab("SHT71"));
        db.addSensorsNameVocab(new SensorsNameVocab("SPD015G"));
        db.addSensorsNameVocab(new SensorsNameVocab("Encoder"));
        db.addSensorsNameVocab(new SensorsNameVocab("PT"));
        db.addSensorsNameVocab(new SensorsNameVocab("WindDir"));
        db.addSensorsNameVocab(new SensorsNameVocab("WindSpeed"));
        db.addSensorsNameVocab(new SensorsNameVocab("Current"));
        db.addSensorsNameVocab(new SensorsNameVocab("DS1820"));
        db.addSensorsNameVocab(new SensorsNameVocab("ADXL345"));
        db.addSensorsNameVocab(new SensorsNameVocab("ACS712"));
        db.addSensorsNameVocab(new SensorsNameVocab("DS18B20"));
        db.addSensorsNameVocab(new SensorsNameVocab("PT100"));
        db.addSensorsNameVocab(new SensorsNameVocab("GSD8"));
        db.addSensorsNameVocab(new SensorsNameVocab("GR"));
        db.addSensorsNameVocab(new SensorsNameVocab("DIRIS A10"));
        db.addSensorsNameVocab(new SensorsNameVocab("TRANSMOTEC DMA-24-40-A-457-LT-POT-IP65"));
        db.addSensorsNameVocab(new SensorsNameVocab("GSD5"));

        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("UTC-HH", 0, 23));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("UTC-MM", 0, 59));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("UTC-SS", 0, 59));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Latitude degree", -180, 180));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Latitude dot", 0, 9999));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Position fix indicator", 0, 3));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Speed", 0, 200));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Course over ground", -360, 360));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Date_year", 2014, 2020));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Date_month", 1, 12));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Date_day", 1, 31));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Magnetic variation", -360, 360));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Mode 1", 0, 3));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Mode 2", 0, 3));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("PDOP", 0, 20));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("HDOP", 0, 20));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("VDOP", 0, 20));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Relative humidity", 0, 100));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Temparature", -20, 120));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Air pressure (pascal Gauge)", 0, 1500));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Rotation", -200, 200));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Battery voltage", 0, 400));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Consumption", 0, 100));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Acceleration", -10, 10));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Volume", 0, 99999));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Radiation", 0, 1500));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Direction", 0, 360));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Current", -20, 50));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Voltage", 0, 500));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Frequency", 0, 65));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Power", 0, 9999));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Power efficiency", -1, 1));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Flow", 0, 9999));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Heat flow", 0, 9999));
        db.addSensorTypeVocab(new SensorTypeVocab("Logic", 0, 1));

        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("-"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("sec"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("min"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("hour"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("day"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("month"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("year"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("°"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("km/h"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("m/s"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("%"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("°C"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("Pa"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("imp/sec"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("1/min"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("m^3"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("m^3/h"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("l/h"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("g"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("l"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("l/min"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("W"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("A"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("V"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("W/m^2"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("Hz"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("var"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("VA"));
        db.addUnitVocab(new UnitVocab("Logic"));


        db.addVehicleCategoryVocab(new VehicleCategoryVocab("N1","Áruszállító gépkocsik legfeljebb 3,5 t össztömeggel"));
        db.addVehicleCategoryVocab(new VehicleCategoryVocab("M1","Személyszállító gépkocsik legfeljebb nyolc ülőhellyel"));
        db.addVehicleCategoryVocab(new VehicleCategoryVocab("M2","Személyszállító gépkocsik több mint nyolc ülőhellyel és legfeljebb 5 t össztömeggel"));
        db.addVehicleCategoryVocab(new VehicleCategoryVocab("M3","Személyszállító gépkocsik több mint nyolc ülőhellyel és több mint 5 t össztömeggel"));
        db.addVehicleCategoryVocab(new VehicleCategoryVocab("N2","Áruszállító gépkocsik 3,5 t - 12 t legnagyobb össztömeggel"));
        db.addVehicleCategoryVocab(new VehicleCategoryVocab("N3","Áruszállító gépkocsik több mint 12 t össztömeggel"));
        db.addVehicleCategoryVocab(new VehicleCategoryVocab("O1","Pótkocsik, legfeljebb 0,75 t össztömeggel"));
        db.addVehicleCategoryVocab(new VehicleCategoryVocab("O2","Pótkocsik, 0,75 t - 3,5 t össztömeggel"));
        db.addVehicleCategoryVocab(new VehicleCategoryVocab("O3","Pótkocsik, 3,5 t - 10 t össztömeggel"));
        db.addVehicleCategoryVocab(new VehicleCategoryVocab("O4","Pótkocsik, több mint 10 t össztömeggel"));
        db.addVehicleCategoryVocab(new VehicleCategoryVocab("L1E","Max. 50 cm3 belsőégésű, vagy max. 4 KW elektromos motorral szerelt kétkerekű motorkerékpár"));
        db.addVehicleCategoryVocab(new VehicleCategoryVocab("L2E","Max. 50 cm3 belsőégésű, vagy max. 4 KW elektromos motorral szerelt háromkerekű motorkerékpár"));
        db.addVehicleCategoryVocab(new VehicleCategoryVocab("L3E","Motorkerékpárok, melyek 45 km/óra sebességnél nagyobb sebességűek, és 50 cm3-nél nagyobb hengerűrtartalmú belsőégésű motorral vannak ellátva"));
        db.addVehicleCategoryVocab(new VehicleCategoryVocab("L4E","45 km/óra sebességnél nagyobb sebességű, 50 cm3-nél nagyobb hengerűrtartalmú belsőégésű motorral ellátott oldalkocsis járművek"));
        db.addVehicleCategoryVocab(new VehicleCategoryVocab("L5E","Háromkerekű járművek (triciklik), 50 cm3-nél nagyobb belsőégésű motorral vannak ellátva, és/vagy a tervezési sebességük nagyobb, mint 45 km/óra"));
        db.addVehicleCategoryVocab(new VehicleCategoryVocab("L6E","Könnyű négykerekű járművek, amelyek saját tömege legfeljebb 350 kg, sebességük max. 45. km/óra, amelyek motorjának hengerűrtartalma max. 50 cm3"));
        db.addVehicleCategoryVocab(new VehicleCategoryVocab("L7E","Egyéb, az L6e kategóriákban fel nem soroltakon kívüli négykerekű járművek, amelyek saját tömege legfeljebb 400 kg"));

    }

}
```

Comment: Where is  db_refill.fill() ?

Comment: it's another class's method

Comment: You are not executing the asynctask! If so than add the code call.

Comment: why u called db_refill.fill() inside while (progressBarStatus < 100) {}?

Comment: where is db_refill.execute()?

Comment: just a silly mistake .... put it out side  while (progressBarStatus < 100) {}

Comment: if i call it outside the loop than the progressbar starts with 100 and never changes

Comment: OMG how can that even possible?

Comment: @Mann if you don't believe me i can record it to video :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to the style of the Progress Dialog

```
        ProgressDialog mProgress = new ProgressDialog(UR_CONTEXT);
        mProgress.setMessage("UR_MESSAGE");
        mProgress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mProgress.setCancelable(false);
        mProgress.show();
```

Comment: thank you i have had like this, but i want to "tell" to user how moch time does he has to wait :)

Comment: @David: given the current structure of your database fill method, you simply can't.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling db_refill.fill() within your while loop which will keep filling your database until the progress is above 100.  This is probably not your intent.

Suggested correction with pseudo-code

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        db_refill.fill();
        while (progressBarStatus < 100) 
        {
            progressBarStatus = db_refill.getStatus();
            publishProgress(progressBarStatus);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: if i call it outside the loop than the progressbar starts with 100 and never changes

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what is trying to be accomplished, as it's tough to follow.  I am under the assumption that perhaps you want to fill the database on one thread and then wait for the database to fill, while giving progress on your database.  In this case you would probably need to call fill before the loop, and then have a check method within the loop updating the progress bar.

Comment: if i call it before the loop it stands on 0 and when its ready jumps on 100 and disappera

Comment: with your edit i get this error msg: The method getStatus() is undefined for the type Db_ReFill

Comment: @David on progressUpdate() is used where u know the time needed to complete the task ... like downloading a file ... in which u know the complete file size of the file... So I suggest to remove  progress dialog STYLE_HORIZONTAL

Comment: Since u dont know the total time taken to complete the tast or the file needed to write in the DB

Comment: @David That's because getStatus() is not a real method.  I don't know what your DB_Refill class is, it's just a suggestion.  And that means your refill method is not on it's own separate thread then if it is working like that; which is where you would be able to accomplish this route.